# How to include lines in a regular expression search which might not be present?

Tags: regular-expressions, search

I'm using a regular expression search which is working as expected.

This searches for [unified diff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff#Unified_format) file entries and works as expected.

```lisp
(re-search-forward
  (concat
    ;; Prefix '+++ '.
    "^"
    "\\-\\-\\-[[:blank:]]+.*\n"
    "\\+\\+\\+[[:blank:]]+.*\n"
    ;; May have trailing text which can be safely ignored.
    "@@[[:blank:]]+.*[[:blank:]]@@")
  nil t 1)
```

However some diffs have leading lines, eg:

```
 // some context text.
diff --git a/my_source.c b/my_source.c
index 43484a57f1c..5985d498606 100644
--- a/my_source.c
+++ b/my_source.c
 // some other context text.
```

My question is:

How can I include lines in the search which may or may not exist?

In this case: `diff` and `index`.

I tried this but it doesn't work, the `\n` literals prevent the following `^` from being detected.

```lisp
(re-search-forward
  (concat
    ;; This fails :(
    "\\(\\|^diff[[:blank:]]+.*\n\\)"
    "\\(\\|^index[[:blank:]]+.*\n\\)"
    ;; Prefix '+++ '.
    "^"
    "\\-\\-\\-[[:blank:]]+.*\n"
    "\\+\\+\\+[[:blank:]]+.*\n"
    ;; May have trailing text which can be safely ignored.
    "@@[[:blank:]]+.*[[:blank:]]@@")
  nil t 1)
```

How can these lines be included in the search if they exist, otherwise left as empty groups if they aren't present?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`?` is the zero-or-one quantifier: `\\(...\\)?` says the group may or may not match anything.

Make it non-capturing if you don't care about backreferences to that group:  `\\(?:...\\)?`

> I tried this but it doesn't work, the `\n` literals prevent the following `^` from being detected.

`^` only has its special meaning in certain positions;  You can't put it anywhere and have it mean "the beginning of a line".  <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(elisp)Regexp Special` explains:

```
 For historical compatibility reasons, ‘^’ can be used
 only at the beginning of the regular expression, or
 after ‘\(’, ‘\(?:’ or ‘\|’.
```

More specifically, if you *do* use it in other positions then it matches a literal `^` character (but if you want to match a `^` then it's preferable -- for the sake of readability -- to escape it, even in these cases where you can get away without escaping it).

But note that you don't need a `^` to match the beginning of a line if the previous matched character was *guaranteed* to be a newline.